# Unable to use JSON.parse in my django template

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a variable data1 in my Django view which has been returned in the following way -

```
def dashboard(request):
   df1 = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
   str1= df1.to_json(orient = 'records')
   data1 = json.loads(str1)
   return render(request, 'dashboard/new 1.html',{'data1' : data1})
```

The variable is then called in the template using javascript

```
 <script type = text/javascript>    
   var ob2 = JSON.parse( {{ data1 }} );
   document.write(ob2);
 </script>
```

This does not show anything on the HTML webpage created. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Do you see any error in the console of the browser when you open that page?

Comment: remove parse and try `document.write("{{data1}}")`;

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting it as a string:

```
<script type = text/javascript>    
  var ob2 = JSON.parse( "{{ data1 }}" );
  document.write(ob2);
</script>
```

If this is not producing the results, I suggest just printing `{{ data1 }}` on screen and seeing exactly what is being returned by Django.

Comment: Or `console.log(data1)` may help more for debugging. Are there any console errors?

Comment: sorry for that ... I added a code that was edited afterwards

Comment: tried it <script type = text/javascript>    
  var ob2 = JSON.parse( "{{ data1 }}" );
  document.write(ob2);
</script>

Comment: What is the output of that variable?

Answer (score 1):

Besides The Brewmaster's answer, the other problems are:

```
data1 = json.loads(str1)
```

That turns the JSON string back into a Python data structure. Just send `str1` itself to the template, and call it `a` as that's what you use in the template:

```
return render(request, 'dashboard/new 1.html',{'a' : str1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by remove `Parse`

```
 <script type = text/javascript>    
   document.write("{{ data1 }}");
 </script>
```